# Render large portion of page using jQuery & AJAX

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ajax, jquery

I have an ASP.NET MVC application with a page that displays a large table of rows & columns of information.

I have a textbox at the top of the page allowing a user to filter the results in the table. I want the user to be able to start typing a word in the textbox and with each keypress, the results in the table to be updated based on the users filter text.

I've done similar things where I simply return a `JsonResult` response from my Controller, with a couple of small bits of data, but am not sure of the recommended approach if I want to essentially re-render my whole table (with the new data within it) upon each keypress?

I should also mention that the ViewModel I intend to use when the page is first loaded (prior to any ajax stuff happening) contains an IPagedList, as the table data needs to be paginated and sortable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would do is to work with JQuery ajax API and also with partial views.

Have a look at following article. It displays how you can be able to manipulate your html seamlessly on ASP.NET MVC :

**Working With JQuery Ajax API on ASP.NET MVC 3.0 - Power of JSON, JQuery and ASP.NET MVC Partial Views**

http://www.tugberkugurlu.com/archive/working-with-jquery-ajax-api-on-asp-net-mvc-3-0-power-of-json-jquery-and-asp-net-mvc-partial-views

Also, following question might help :

[How to pass an array through in JQuery Ajax and how to concieve it in server side?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7386181/how-to-pass-an-array-through-in-jquery-ajax-and-how-to-concieve-it-in-server-side)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the templates to render the html.

i.e Parametrized html + json = to be rendered html

[MicroTemplates](http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-micro-templating/)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at http://knockoutjs.com/ it could be a very good fit for you

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [DataTables](http://datatables.net/) plug-in for jQuery. It may match your requirements and provide exactly what you need.